# Email client with encrypted remote storage

Tags: windows, email, encryption

I'm looking to replace my current e-mail software but have been unable to find anything which fits what I want.

I currently use an e-mail system which encrypts my mail store on my local device, but I want to move to storing this data in the cloud. However, I don't want to trust a cloud storage provider with unencrypted e-mails, so I don't want to move to a hosted e-mail system.

One option would be to continue using my existing software, but move the email database into an encrypted container (such as truecrypt) and store the container in the cloud, however this feels like rather a hack to me.

So, what I'm looking for is:

- A fully featured e-mail client (with rule based filtering into folders etc.).
- Store e-mail database in the cloud but where encryption is done locally and the cloud provider never has access to the keys.
- Ideally have the ability for multiple clients to access the same online e-mail store (even if just one at once)
- Ideally have a block storage friendly design (to minimise the data transfer and differential backup volume)

Is there anything available which can do what I want?